# Importing django.contrib.auth.urls does not play well with existing admin templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, django-login

I've been trying to follow [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#using-the-views) on using builtin Django templates to login/logout nonstaff users on a Django (1.9) site. In particular, I modified the urlconf by adding

`url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))`

which brings in /login and /logout endpoints and views with default template names preprogrammed.

The default template names for login and logout are `registration/login.html` and `registration/logged_out.html`.  The first one doesn't exist anywhere, so I assumed I should create a `templates/registration/` and create the login template, which I did. I thought the same thing should work for the logout, except it doesn't.

What actually happens is that the template resolves to `django.contrib.admin.templates.registration.logged_out.html`. This is pretty but stinks because the login link points to the admin login, which no nonstaff user will be able to use.

I really wish I could use the urlconf above, use the default template names, but write my own templates. Isn't this possible? The alternative seems to be repeating a bunch of stuff and that isn't very Pythonic.

I imagine it might involve modification of the `TEMPLATES` setting, or changing the orders of something else in the settings.

Whatever the solution is, I hope it does not interfere with the proper resolution of the admin templates (i.e. it would be bad if those started using my new templates.)

---

Requested details:

I created a `login.html` in `(appname)/templates/registration/`, and it works just fine when visiting the login url.

I created a `logged_out.html` in `(appname)/templates/registration/` also, but discovered that when visiting the logout url, I got the admin site logged_out template (the one that says "Thanks for spending some quality time with the Web site today."

My templates setting:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
         'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
         'DIRS': [],
         'APP_DIRS': True,
         'OPTIONS': {
             'debug': True,
             'context_processors': [
                 'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                 'django.template.context_processors.request',
                 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
             ],
         },
    },
]

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'app',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles'
)
```

Project structure (omitting what I guess is nonessential, and using some generic names.)

```
project/
    app/
        templates/
            app/
            registration/
                login.html
                logged_out.html
        models.py
        views.py
        admin.py
    gettingstarted/
        static/
        settings.py
        urls.py
```

The structure may look a bit weird since it was adapted starting from the Heroku "Getting started with python" app.

### Update

I finally struck upon the right search terms in the Django bug tracker and found that is [a known issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20372). Disappointingly it's already three years old with no comment in the past two years. I guess I will just have to bite the bullet and define my own urls that use templates on a different path.

Comment: Creating `registration/logged_out.html` and `registration/login.html` in the templates folder is the right way to do it. `logged_out.html` should work in the same way `login.html` does. Does one work for you but not the other? Can you post your project and templates folder structure as well as your `TEMPLATES` setting?

Comment: @yprez Thanks for responding, and sorry for the delay in response. I've tried to add the information you requested. Let me know what else to add.

Comment: In your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting in `settings.py`, does your app (`project.app`) come before `'django.contrib.auth'` or after? It should come before so the templates are overloaded properly...

Comment: @yprez Thanks for the idea, but I have bad news. My app was much later than `django.contrib.auth` so I moved it to just before `django.contrib.auth`. However, all the symptoms are still the same as before: my template is not being used.

Comment: Does overriding `login.html` work properly?

Comment: And can you post your INSTALLED_APPS as well?

Comment: @yprez Done. Btw, in the meantime I tried putting my app above `django.contrib.admin` and discovered *then* that it would use my logout template. However, so did the *admin site*, so that's no good. The installed apps now appear as in the post.

Comment: @yprez And another update, I found out that this ideal usage isn't possible due to a 3-year old bug in Django https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20372  Kind of sad the documentation outlines this strategy that doesn't work.

Comment: Nice, I thought that registration templates came from `contrib.auth`, and not `contrib.admin` (in general it's better to place your project apps after django built in apps). I'll write a detailed answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django's template lookup is done top down by the order of `INSTALLED_APPS`. Meaning that if you want to override a template, the overriding template app should be listed above the overriden one in the admin.

In this case, `project.app` should be placed above `django.contrib.admin` so when creating `/registration/logout.html` it'll be loaded before the admin template.

In general, the recommended order of installed apps is: project -> 3rd party apps -> django builtins. It also affects static files finders.

---

Because of a [bug in Django](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20372), overriding the `registration/logged_out.html` template overrides the admin "logged_out" template as well.

You can include the logout view specifically and specify a different "logged out" template or `next_page` (the view where it redirects after logout):

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/'}, name='logout'),
    url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

This will redirect to `/` after logout. It can also be a named url.

Or to change the `logged_out` template location use:

```
url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'template_name': 'logged_out.html'}, name='logout'),
```

And then create `logged_out.html` in `project/app/templates/`.

I would use the first option if you want to redirect the user back to the home page after logout, and the 2nd if you want to display a "logged out" message.

Comment: Thanks: this is very helpful.

Comment: What if I want to retain the admin logout page while putting my app at the top of the installed-apps? How can I get django to recognize the difference between my /registration directory and the admin /registration?

Comment: You can't, the first one matching the name will be returned. The only solution is to give your template a different name (filename or path) e.g. `custom_logged_out.html` instead of `registration/logged_out.html`.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I've since done that and things are working OK. Any plans to work on the bug? :)

Comment: The bug is a bit challenging because it's a breaking change, not sure how to deal with that...